# How to keep elasticsearch data in sync with MySql?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using ***spring-data-jpa*** to persist data to ***MySql*** and I've recently implemented ***spring-data-elasticsearch*** to insert data into ES on INSERT (e.g new photo is uploaded).

Now obviously this only inserts the initial data, soon after the it will become stale.

Lets take ***instagram*** as an example:

1. You post a photo

   - Photo (photo object - description, location, tags)
   - User (user who posted)
   - No likes (0)
   - No comments (0)

All this data would be inserted under a ***photo*** index in *elasticsearch*. When users start *liking* and *commenting* on the *photo*, the data will become *stale*.

How can we fix this?!

> Would we create a ***cronjob/task*** which would go through ***all***
>   the photos and insert each of them into elasticsearch every X minutes
>   (this would mean removing all current indexes for ***photo***)?! This
>   seems like it'd take a long time and use a lot of resources!

*Instead of inserting all the data again, would we simply update all the current elasticsearch indexes?*

What have you done to combat this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to keep a last updated type of column in the database and update it whenever there is a change.

Your indexer then just needs to query out anything from the database since the last time you successfully indexed data.

Depending on how reliable you can make it, you may still need to do a full comparison periodically.

Comment: hi, what is indexer here?